# Why doesn't my multi-meter diode tester work on this LED?

Tags: led, multimeter, testing

I own a TENMA 72-7720 Multi-meter with LCD/continuity tester:

[image]

I've used this on other LEDs to test, no problem, using the diode tester setting (approximately 2:00 on the dial by the hold button)

I purchased a large quantity of [Purple (UV) LEDs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AUI4VTM) that arrived yesterday.  When I tested them using the above tester, I got nothing.  I tested about half a dozen of the 600 I ordered and none worked so I decided to test them using another means.  I hooked one up to my current project (8x8x8 LED cube) and the LED worked fine.

Since I'm going to be making over a thousand solder connections with these things I want to make sure they're good before I use them and to test periodically during assembly.

So why isn't my tester working?

Comment: ...You didn't mention *how* you tested them.

Comment: Tested what, how? Forward voltage with the diode test? Resistance?

Comment: I'm sorry, thought it was obvious.  I set the multi-meter on the diode tester setting connected it to the LED.  What should I add to the question to improve it?

Comment: Your meter may not drive that high a voltage for diode test. I suggest you make up a little test circuit.

Comment: It's probably down to the meter not putting out enough forward voltage to make UV (and blue or white) LEDs conduct. Normal diodes need about 0.6V, these LEDs need 3V.

Comment: That makes sense.  Guess there's a side project coming my way now - build a tester. :)

Comment: On my Fluke benchtop meter the 2KΩ range worked even for white, green, and blue LEDs.  It actually lit them up so the continuity test is visual.  The various Ω ranges use different currents.  The 2K range worked for me, the other ranges did not work.

Comment: I'll give that a try as well.  I've got 600 of the damn things so if one gets blown out, I'll live. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those LEDs have a typical forward voltage of 3V.
Your multimeter's Diode/Continuity test feature reads anything above 2.8V as an open circuit.
[image]
from [this link](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/content/ProductData/Manuals/72-7725.pdf)

The Diode Test function on multimeters isn't really intended to test LEDs. Normal diodes have a forward voltage under 1V.

'Old' Red/Yellow/Green LEDs would typically have forward voltages in the 1.2V to 2.5V range, but these new-fangled white/blue/purple/pink thingies are often 3V or more.

Answer (score 3):

LEDs typically have a much lower maximum reverse voltage than ordinary diodes.

Apply a higher reverse voltage than it's spec'd for and you are likely to damage the LED.

Your LED would appear to have a Vrrm of 5 V, a min/typ/max forward drop of 3.0/3.4/4.0 V and typical continuous operating current of 20 mA.

(I couldn't find an official data sheet on your part but I found this info' on a dubious-ish source. But they are typical figures for such an LED so I would go with them.)

So you should build a test fixture with a 4.5 V supply in series with 100 R to put 10 mA through an LED with the typical 3.4 V drop. Consider putting the output of a 7805 regulator through a 1N4001 diode then through 100 R then to your LED.

**Don't build a tester running off a 9 V or 12 V supply or anything like that.** That will damage your LEDs.

Comment: The only real datasheet for parts like that that I could find indicated a built in zener diode for ESD protection which means reverse voltage wouldn't be an issue as long as the short circuit current wasn't over 100mA.

Comment: Cheers @Andrew but not what I found and I'd say that's a rare feature in an LED. And since the lower voltage is easy, why take a pointless risk :-)

Comment: Well it would at least solve the issue of whether the part is good or not. ;-) But your point is taken.

Comment: @TonyM I'm thinking about using this design but modifying it to have probes instead of a fitting (so I can test banks of LEDs) - but it runs off a 9v battery.  Do you think it will be safe for these LEDs?
http://www.instructables.com/id/LED-tester-with-adjustable-current/

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo, it's a very neat idea. They use the three LEDs as both indicator and voltage reference. I can't tell you you can't go wrong if you use it. But I can say that provided the voltage across its probes is well less than 5 V, preferably below 4.5 V, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

As Trevor & Finbarr's comments indicate it's probably a voltage issue.

The diode mode on a meter puts a current limited voltage across the probes and looks for a current flow. It then indicates the voltage drop measured.

It'll probably be using around 3V for this bias voltage. A normal diode needs 0.6-0.7 and a red or green LED normally needs 1.5-2V. Which means the diode mode will test them just fine.

But your LEDs will need a forward voltage in excess of 3V and so the meter can't test them.

To test them put a 5 V voltage source and 1k resistor in series and then measure the voltage across the LED. If you see your supply voltage or 0V then the LED is dead, if you see just over 3V the LED is good. Supply voltage or around 0.6V could also indicate the diode is backwards depending upon the exact nature of the part.
Potentially a higher voltage could be used if more convenient however as indicated by TonyM this may risk damage to the part if inserted the wrong way around. It depends upon the reverse voltage characteristics of the part which are unspecified.